# How to find matching python data frame values with other data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update in df1['Result'] as True or False if df1['Field1'] values exist in other dataframe df2['SersName']

Please help...

df1:

```
Field1          Field2  Result
2020RATIO001001 A       TRUE
2020RATIO001003 B       TRUE
2020RATIO001005 C       TRUE
2020RATIO001XYZ D       FALSE
2020RATIO001123 E       FALSE
```

df2:

```
SersName        Field2
2020RATIO001001 1
2020RATIO001003 2
2020RATIO001005 3
2020RATIO001007 4
2020RATIO001009 5
2020RATIO001011 6
2020RATIO001013 7
2020RATIO001015 8
```

I tried below script:

```
SeriesFileNameMap = df1['Field1'].set_index('Field1')
SeriesFileNameMap.update(df2.set_index('SersName'))
df1['Result'] = SeriesFileNameMap.values
```

Comment: @FLab, updated, check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isin`

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""Field1 Field2
2020RATIO001001 A
2020RATIO001003 B
2020RATIO001005 C
2020RATIO001XYZ D
2020RATIO001123 E"""),sep=" ")

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""SersName Field2
2020RATIO001001 1
2020RATIO001003 2
2020RATIO001005 3
2020RATIO001007 4
2020RATIO001009 5
2020RATIO001011 6
2020RATIO001013 7
2020RATIO001015 8"""),sep=" ")

df1['Result'] = df1['Field1'].isin(df2['SersName'])
```

The resultant df1 is:

```
Field1  Field2  Result
0   2020RATIO001001 A   True
1   2020RATIO001003 B   True
2   2020RATIO001005 C   True
3   2020RATIO001XYZ D   False
4   2020RATIO001123 E   False
```